# Login to on one page and then get another page passing all cookies from the first page along

Tags: php, post, curl, get

I am trying to Get from my Api,Im using curl in php to log into on one page and
then get another page passing all cookies from the first page along with you but I keep getting Access denied!!

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.supersaas.com/api/users");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?account=myname&password=mypassword");

ob_start();      // prevent any output
curl_exec ($ch); // execute the curl command
ob_end_clean();  // stop preventing output

curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookieFileName");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.supersaas.com/api/users?id=12");

$buf2 = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

echo "<PRE>".htmlentities($buf2);
```

What's wrong with this code????
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your login didn't successful, hence you had invalid cookie in the file and got your second curl request denied from the server.

Remove the `?` mark from the `?account`. So it will be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "account=myname&password=mypassword");
```

Comment: I can log in successfully to the first page, but I cant log in to the second page 
the ignore the ?, It's my mistake from testing.


Thanks again